# C programming problem pointers and arrays 2d

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

Q2: Implelment the follwoing function `ArrPrintMatrix(char *(p)[7])` which prints the content of the `matrix[m][7] ={"SHAHBAZ","AYAZ"}` in to 3x3 Matrix

*Sample Output*

```
S H A                      
H B A                       
Z A Y ..
```

My question is : here is code only problem i am getting is a space after one name is completed..how to remove that space . I have this question in my assignments , that have to be submitted on sunday (11-11-18)..
My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void ArrPrintMatrix(char *p);//function declaration
    char matrix[2][8] ={"SHAHBAZ","AYAZ"};//2d array initiliation
    ArrPrintMatrix(&matrix[0][0]);//calling function with base address

}

void ArrPrintMatrix(char *p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(i>=9)//since 3 by 3 matrix is required
            break;
        if(i==3||i==6||i==9)//changing line since 3 by 3 matrix is needed
            printf("\n");
        printf("%c ",*(p+i));//prininting chracters

    }
}
```

Comment: Nasty question. It tells you to write a function like this `ArrPrintMatrix(char *(p)[7]) ` and gives you a string that's 8 characters long ("SHAHBAZ" plus a terminating zero).

Comment: thank you so much for quick reply . I donot understand hot to use `ArrPrintMatrix(char *(p)[7])` and to pass it to function can you please please help me ....please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow-on to my other answer, if you do use my logic to skip over the `'\0'` that terminates the strings, you will need to use a different variable to keep track of how many characters you've actually printed, and just let `i` keep track of where you are in the input string(s).  Like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void ArrPrintMatrix(char *p);//function declaration
    char matrix[2][8] ={"SHAHBAZ","AYAZ"};//2d array initiliation
    ArrPrintMatrix(&matrix[0][0]);//calling function with base address

}

void ArrPrintMatrix(char *p)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0, j=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(j>=9)//since 3 by 3 matrix is required
            break;
        if(j==3||j==6||j==9)//changing line since 3 by 3 matrix is needed
            printf("\n");
        if (*(p+i)==0) continue; //don't try to print the trailing '\0'
        printf("%c ",*(p+i));//prininting chracters
        j++; //increment counter of characters actually printed

    }
}
```

Output:

```
S H A 
H B A 
Z A Y
```

Note the use of the `j` variable, and how it is incremented with `j++` only *after* actually printing a character.

Comment: `if (*(p+i)==0) continue; //don't try to print the trailing '\0'`
I donot understand this point , i mean why donot i say thay if *(p+j)=='0'??

Comment: `'0'` is very different from `0`;  `'\0'` on the other hand equates to `0`

Comment: you could use either `if (*(p+i)==0)` or `if (*(p+i)=='\0')`, but not `if *(p+j)=='0'`, which is what you have in your comment

Comment: can you help me understand this code please your explanation is tremendous
`#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void ArrPrintMatrix(char (*p)[8]);//function declaration
    char matrix[2][8] ={"SHAHBAZ","AYAZ"};//2d array initiliation
    ArrPrintMatrix(matrix);//calling function with base address

}
void ArrPrintMatrix(char (*p)[8])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (k != 9)
    {
        if (p[i][j] == '\0') {
            ++i;
            j = 0;
        }
        printf("%c ", p[i][j++]);
        ++k;
        if(k%3 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}`

Comment: Sorry about that i have implemented your answer . But just for the sake of understanding  i asked you, cause i like your explanation...

Comment: I've edited @Yunbin Liu's answer with code comments; my edits need to be reviewed by Yunbin Liu, who will decide whether or not to accept my edits

Comment: yes of course you can ask the reason is he said that :  " It tells you to write a function like this ArrPrintMatrix(char *(p)[7]) and gives you a string that's 8 characters long ("SHAHBAZ" plus a terminating zero)"

that statement is given in question of the coding , thats why dude.

Comment: OH Dear (@landru27) thank you so much for making code comments to @Yunbin Liu's answer please share it ...

Comment: @ÂftãbBãlôçh  regarding the use of `char (*p)[8]`, like I said in my original answer, there are lots of things I would do differently that the code you wrote, but I generally try to answer the exact question being asked, to keep the answer focused; I have found that it creates less confusion;  but I'm glad that both Yunbin Liu and I were both able to assist

Comment: @ÂftãbBãlôçh  Yunbin Liu accepted my edits;  please also consider up-voting one or both of my answers, since they helped you along with Yunbin Liu's answer; thanks much!

Comment: absolutely why not dude

Comment: @ÂftãbBãlôçh  it looks like you changed the accepted answer; Yunbin Liu's answer is a very fine answer and I think you should keep it as the accepted answer;  I was only asking for an upvote

Comment: i am very beginner to stackoverflow  so things are confusing are stackoverflow...
I like both of the answer but the strategy you have applied , I mean according to my coding love it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `char (*p)[8]` not `char* p`

The following `code` could wrok:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void ArrPrintMatrix(char (*p)[8]);//function declaration
    char matrix[2][8] ={"SHAHBAZ","AYAZ"};//2d array initiliation
    ArrPrintMatrix(matrix);//calling function with base address

}
void ArrPrintMatrix(char (*p)[8])
{
    // i will point to one of the strings in the set of strings
    // j will point into the string we are inspecting
    // k will count how many characters we have printed
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    // we only need to print the first 9 printable characters we find
    while (k != 9)
    {
        // if we have reached the end of an input string (the null-terminator),
        // then move on to the next element in the array, and reset
        // the string pointer to the beginning of the new string
        if (p[i][j] == '\0') {
            ++i;
            j = 0;
        }

        // print the character we are now pointing at,
        // and increment the string pointer
        printf("%c ", p[i][j++]);

        // keep count of how many characters we have printed
        ++k;

        // if k is divisible by 3, start a new row
        if(k%3 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: perfectly done i must appreciate bou unfortunately i don't understand how this code is working ..I also have exams on monday :(

Comment: can you please tech me your code by commenting or something like dry run..I would be thankfull

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that there is a trailing `'\0'` at the end of `SHAHBAZ`, which you are also "printing", but because `'\0'` does not have a character representation, you are seeing what looks like an 'extra' space.

Here is the smallest change I can think of to address this exact problem; add:

```
if (*(p+i)==0) continue; //don't try to print the trailing '\0'
```

just above your existing line:

```
printf("%c ",*(p+i));//prininting chracters
```

Output:

```
S H A 
H B A 
Z A
```

There are other things I would do differently than how you are doing them, but this addresses your exact question, using your coding style.